# Receive memory warning on console

Tags: ios

My app crashes after showing Receive memory warning on console.

On surfing I found a solution to remove memory leaks but I am unable to remove memory leaks.

Here is screenshot showing leaks, with some percents.

[image]

How do I solve these leaks?

**NOTE** : I created this method in singleton class.

Comment: place the code inside-(MutableArray*)getData{ @autoreleasepool{ your code goes here} return mutableArrayInstance;}

Comment: Memory warning not only occurs because of the leaks, if you load too much data into memory you can exceed the amount of memory available for the app. This can easily happen if you load lots of data into singleton which is never released itself and doesn't release any data "inside". Regarding your memory leaks, you are retaining this objects but never release them, you need to balance each alloc/retain with release or autorelease (make sure not to manually release autoreleased objects).

Answer (score 0):

As this question is old and hope the user must get a solution.But i think to write answer for this to help other users in future.
This scenario comes in these cases:-

1) you're using a lot of memory and available memory is low.

2) Not releasing data that are not in use.

you have to check these leaks:-

1)Use instruments to check memory leaks and where its leaking(Suggestion for them who got memory issues).

2)By seeing your code it seems to be memory leaks when you are allocating array in the singleton class.

3)Not releasing arrays.

Please checkout these links for better understanding of allocations.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3637159/1865424

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3898015/1865424